# How to connect client android app with admin website

Tags: firebase

I have created an android app on android studio with firebase database.

Now I want to develop an administrative website through which the admin will control all the operations of the app.

I want to know how to connect the app to the website. Also, should the database be connected to the app or the website?

Comment: If the app acts only as reading database content then whatever changes you make through the web will also reflect on the app because firebase is realtime.  If you mean to send something from mobile to web then you're talking about  web or appserver. That's  another thing.

Answer (score 0):

Your website doesn't need to be directly connected to the app or vice versa. That is what firebase is for. When using the website or app, you connect directly to firebase. When data changes in the database, you can reflect these changes on both the website and app.

So there is no direct link between the app and website. They are just interfaces to manipulate and view data in firebase.

Comment: so both the app and website can be connected to same firebase database?

Comment: Yes they can as well as they should be connected to the same firebase databse. Database admins should have control over the data. If they are connected to a different database, how can they do this? If this has helped you, please upvote and accept my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Basically your quesion is "How can you connect your Android application to a web server".
You need to look at the URLConnection class. An example is here http://www.devx.com/wireless/Art.... If you are writing the server side web service, I suggest making it a RESTful service returning JSON data (as that is easier to deal with on the handset)

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please consider using some code examples and expounding on your answer